How to type check all elements in an array in TypeScript
How would I type check all elements in an array? CUrrently I am trying to do it with .every(), but the compiler is still unhappy. This return [animal, ...animals] does not work.
interface Dog {
    breed: string,
    age: number,
    alive: boolean
}

interface Cat {
    origin: string,
    height: number,
    furious: boolean
}

interface Fish {
    water: 'salty' | 'sweet'
    hemishphere: 'north' | 'south'
}

type Animal = Cat | Dog | Fish
type Animals = Cat[] | Dog[] | Fish[]


const isDog = (item: any): item is Dog => typeof item === 'object' &&
    item !== null &&
    "breed" in item &&
    "age" in item &&
    "alive" in item

const isCat = (item: any): item is Cat => typeof item === 'object' &&
    item !== null &&
    "origin" in item &&
    "height" in item &&
    "furious" in item

const isFish = (item: any): item is Fish => typeof item === 'object' &&
    item !== null &&
    "water" in item &&
    "hemishphere" in item


const animals: Animals = []

const setAnimals = (animal: Animal): Animals => {
    if(isDog(animal) && animals.every(a => isDog(a))) {
        return [animal, ...animals]    
    } else if(isCat(animal)) {
        return [animal]
    } else if (isFish(animal)) {
        return [animal]
    } else {
        return []
    }
    
}


Here is a PlayGround

a => isDog(a) is a long way of saying isDog that just hides from TS that it's a type guard. Use just every(isDog). OR wait until TS5.5 which gets inferred type predicates and the problem goes away by itself (but you probably still want just every(isDog) unless you have some important reason for the extra indirection). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Just put isDog to every() directly, seems a proper way to narrow animals to Dog[]:
if(isDog(animal) && animals.every(isDog)) {


First ensure your type then check the array
let animals: Animals = []

const setAnimals = (animal: Animal): Animals => {
    if(isDog(animal)) {
        if(animals.every(isDog)) {
            animals = [animal, ...animals]
        } else {
            animals = [animal]
        }
    } else if(isCat(animal)) {
        if(animals.every(isCat)) {
            animals = [animal, ...animals]
        } else {
            animals = [animal]
        }
    } else if(isFish(animal)) {
        if(animals.every(isFish)) {
            animals = [animal, ...animals]
        } else {
            animals = [animal]
        }
    }
    return animals
}

